# Pig cannot dump after new bag generated

Tags: casting, apache-pig

This is my script:

```
Customer = LOAD '/home/hduser/PigSandbox/PigOut/Customer_Base.json/part-r-00000' USING JsonLoader();

CustomerPost = FOREACH Customer GENERATE ((chararray)Email
,DateModified
,Age
,City
,Name
,Occupation
,State
,Address1
,Address2
,Company
,Country
,DateOfBirth
,Fax
,Phone
,PostalCode);

DUMP CustomerPost;
```

This is the error I get:

```
java.lang.Exception: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 1075: Received a bytearray from the UDF or Union from two different Loaders. Cannot determine how to convert the bytearray to string.
```

All I want to do is cast the Email from a `bytearray` to a `chararray`. If there is a better way of doing this than generating a new bag please let me know. If not how can I get what I have working? Or at least what does this error mean?

My pig version is 0.14.0 from Nov 16 2014

Here is an example row :

```
{"Email" : "foo@bar.com", "DateModified":"2014-12-27T07:36:38.000-05:00","Age":"10-20","City":"Some Location","Name":"foo","Occupation":"engineer","State":"ok","Address1":"foo lane","Address2":null,"Company":"lorem","Country":"us","DateOfBirth":"1969","Fax":"555-555-5555","Phone":"555-555-5555","PostalCode":"12345"}
```

and here is the schema file

```
{"fields":[{"name":"Email","type":50,"description":"autogenerated from Pig Field Schema","schema":null},{"name":"DateModified","type":30,"description":"autogenerated from Pig Field Schema","schema":null},{"name":"Age","type":55,"description":"autogenerated from Pig Field Schema","schema":null},{"name":"City","type":55,"description":"autogenerated from Pig Field Schema","schema":null},{"name":"Name","type":55,"description":"autogenerated from Pig Field Schema","schema":null},{"name":"Occupation","type":55,"description":"autogenerated from Pig Field Schema","schema":null},{"name":"State","type":55,"description":"autogenerated from Pig Field Schema","schema":null},{"name":"Address1","type":55,"description":"autogenerated from Pig Field Schema","schema":null},{"name":"Address2","type":55,"description":"autogenerated from Pig Field Schema","schema":null},{"name":"Company","type":55,"description":"autogenerated from Pig Field Schema","schema":null},{"name":"Country","type":55,"description":"autogenerated from Pig Field Schema","schema":null},{"name":"DateOfBirth","type":55,"description":"autogenerated from Pig Field Schema","schema":null},{"name":"Fax","type":55,"description":"autogenerated from Pig Field Schema","schema":null},{"name":"Phone","type":55,"description":"autogenerated from Pig Field Schema","schema":null},{"name":"PostalCode","type":55,"description":"autogenerated from Pig Field Schema","schema":null}}
```

Comment: Can you share a test input file ?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Some of the data has sensitive information but I can give you a mock row.